# Can you setup access to NetezzaSQL servers for Jenkins to automate a job virtually?

Tags: python, sql, jenkins, netezza

We are trying to get all of our scripts to run in cloud through Jenkins, however Jenkins seems to have an issue with connecting\identifying the ODBC connections for NetezzaSQL. We have setup a VM where we dump our files in a bitbucket repository and then reference in Jenkins Jobs.

I've done research to see if Jenkins supports NetezzaSQL, or if it even can update on cloud with no conclusive evidence.

Our general connection code is

```
conn_string = "DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=NDWNetezzaProd;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s" % (database, user, Password)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, AutoCommit=False)
```

And here I believe that Jenkins should identify the credentials and still run the update?

The error I get is as folows:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>   (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: There is a million possible reasons for that error. The most likely one: ODBC driver is not properly installed/configured on the (Jenkins) server. Can you connect to netezza on that server outside Jenkins ? Can you even ping the server name or access the server:port with telnet?

Comment: Hi! Yes, we didn't have admin access to the server. Created the connection there using some Netezza install files.! Thanks!